Gauss's Law vs Image charges
Consider a grounded shell of radius $R$, inside is a point charge $q$ at a distance $a$ from the centre. Now, this charge would induce an amount of charge $-q$ on the conductor, whose field would be the same as that of a charge $-q\frac{a}{R}$ at a distance $\frac{R^2}{a}$. Now say we want the field at a distance $x$, $ (x< R)$ from the centre.

Due to Gauss Law, the field inside the charged sphere is zero (I have a strong disbelief towards this), so the only contribution is due to the point charge and hence the field strength is $\frac{Kq}{x^2}$.

Because of the method of point charges, the field should be $\frac{Kq}{x^2}$ due to the point charge and $\frac{-Kqa}{Rd^2}$ due to the image charge, (here, the $d$ is the distance of the point $X$ from the image charge).


These arguments contradict each other, so which one should be correct?

You are confusing things. The method of images does not provide you with the potential inside a conductor; it only gives you the potential outside. The idea of the method is that you should look for a distribution of fictitious charges inside the conductor that would produce a potential outside the conductor equal to what the charge distribution on the surface generates. This never provides information about the inside of the conductor which, as you mentioned, if grounded will have zero potential inside (and will always have zero field inside).
If you are familiar with differential equations, the goal is to solve Laplace's equation $\nabla^2\Phi = \rho/\epsilon_0$ throughout the entire space. Since there is only a point charge, we actually have $\nabla^2\Phi = q/\epsilon_0 \delta(r')$, where $r'$ is the position of your point charge. As you want the potential to be zero on the surface of the conductor, you add the boundary condition $\Phi(r) = 0$ if $r$ is on the surface of the conductor. This problem can be difficult to solve, which is why we use the method of images to simplify it. But note that this method only serves to solve Laplace's equation outside the conductor, because since there are no charges inside the conductor, we must have $\nabla^2\Phi = 0$ in its interior. The final question of the method is: "Is there a charge distribution $\rho_I$ such that if we replace the conductor with this distribution, then the potential generated by it outside the region is the same as that generated by the induced charges on the conductor in our original problem?" This distribution so will satisfy $\nabla\Phi=0$ outisde the conductor, so it's the homogeneous solution of the Laplace equation (the particular solution is just the potential generated by the point charge). As $\nabla\Phi_I=\rho_I/\epsilon_0$ inside the condutor, this solution is only valid outside of it. In this case, the boundary condition of the potential generated by image charges is $\Phi_I(r)-\dfrac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\dfrac{1}{|r - r'|}$ if $r$ is on the surface of the conductor.

"The method of images does not provide you with the potential inside a conductor; it only gives you the potential outside" cf. Purcell's E&M Problem 3.13 for the exact problem described in the OP, which uses the method of images to find the potential inside the shell
